# ExpandableListView sample from Google

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I just tried the current Google sample for [`ExpandableListiew`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html):

This sample seem very simple and easy to use, but what I would like to do is to say that one of the category has no child. I removed all the children but the problem is that the arrow still appears on this current line.

For instance, imagine that I remove all *"Cat Names"*, the arrow is still there and when I click on it, the arrow just change. How to remove this arrow and launch an activity instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're talking about the arrow that is used to collapse/expand the list then you can remove it by using setGroupIndicator()

in the activity you can call

```
getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(null);
```

that will remove the arrow permanently though. If you want to only hide it if the list is empty you can do it through xml attributes like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145090/expandablelistview-hide-indicator-for-groups-with-no-children)

To launch an activity when the list is expanded/collapsed you can override onGroupExpanded (or collapsed) in your ListAdapter implementation and used that to fire up your activity

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you want a specific area of your activity to be refreshed when you come back from another activity; you got to write in the onResume() method.

Steps:
1 – In the Activity you want it to be refreshed, override the onResume() method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // TODO: PUT YOUR REFRESH CODE IN HERE
}
```

2- You will need to refresh your Expandable Adapter.

I suggest you take the same code you used to instantiate your expandable list and put it again, like follows:

```
SimpleExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter =
    new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
        this,
        YourPrentsList, // List of your parent 
        R.layout.parents_layout,    // Layout for the Parents
        new String[] { "groupKey" },    // Key in the Group Data maps to display
        new int[] { 1 },        
        childrenList,   // List of the children
        R.layout.childs_layout, // Layout of the children
        new String[] { "keys"}, 
        new int[] { 1}  
    );
setListAdapter( expandableListAdapter );
```

I hope this solves your concern...
Thanks,

Mohamed.

Comment: Your reply is unfortunately off-topic. I was asking to remove the arrow when a parent has no child...

Comment: @Profete162, It was a while since I answered this question, When I read question and answer now I don't know in what I was thinking... sorry if I spammed your question man. Did you solve the problem anyway?

Comment: Don't be sorry, you tried to help me! Unfortunately, it has been a while for me too! As I could'nt find an answer I used an Alertdialog and a ListView to display the child, if there are available. If there is no child, I just go to next activity.