# How to use an item inside ExpandableListView as normal ListView item

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, android-adapter

I have an ExandableListView and the following BaseExpandableListAdapter :

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Activity context;
    private Map<String, List<String>> navItemsCollection;
    private List<String> groupList;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> groupItems,
                                 Map<String, List<String>> navItemsCollection) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groupList = groupItems;
        this.navItemsCollection = navItemsCollection;
    }

    public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return navItemsCollection.get(groupList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String laptop = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_child_item, null);
        }

        TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.laptop);

        item.setText(laptop);
        return convertView;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return navItemsCollection.get(groupList.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groupList.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_group_item, null);
        }
        TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.laptop);
        item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        item.setText(getGroup(groupPosition));
        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want some of the rows of the expandable list view to behave just normally like a ListView and don't contain the arrow as well. Means clicking on it should call a function.
Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: you can handle this in your adapter, create one imageView in your row and remove arrow indicator from expandable list, and every time you want just invisible your image

Comment: Only removing the arrow would work ?

Comment: what is your mean about `removing the arrow would work`? for removing arrow see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853305/how-can-i-completely-hide-the-groupindicator-of-an-expandablelistview

Comment: Try to check this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728513/expandandable-listview-with-child-items-at-root