# Expandandable listview with child items at root

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I'm trying to make a listview with the following structure:

```
Listview
    -> child
    -> child
    -> group
           -> child
           -> child
    -> child
```

How would I go about acomplishing this?

Do I have to get a group to act like a child or is it possible to do it properly like so:

I have an object MenuRow

```
public class MenuRow {
public String title;

public MenuRow(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

}
```

then I have the MenuGroup and MenuChild that extend MenuRow, this allows me to do the following:

```
    ArrayList<MenuRow> menu = new ArrayList<MenuRow>();
    menu.add(new MenuChild("row 1"));
    menu.add(new MenuChild("row 2"));
    MenuGroup group = new MenuGroup("group");
    MenuChild groupChild = new MenuChild("group child");
    group.items.add(groupChild);
    menu.add(group);
```

I can't seem to figure how I should go about my buisness in the adapter.

```
@Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        MenuRow row = menu.get(groupPosition);
        if (row instanceof MenuGroup) {
            ArrayList<MenuChild> chList = ((MenuGroup) row).getItems();
        }
        else{
                return null;
        }

        return chList;
    }
```

this method for example isn't really adapted to my solution. How should I go about trying to accomplish my goal? do I need to use a different adapter? (my current one extend BaseExpandableListAdapter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already worked with such a problem and here's the approach i used:

And created a class object to be used as a left menu item for both children and parent views

```
public class LeftMenuItem {

    int mTextId;
    int mImageId;
    //Action to be taken after clicking on the item
    String mAction;

    public LeftMenuItem(int textId, int imageId,String action) {
        this.mTextId = textId;
        this.mImageId = imageId;
        this.mAction = action;
    }

    public int getTextId() {
        return mTextId;
    }

    public void setTextId(int textId) {
        this.mTextId = textId;
    }

    public int getImageId() {
        return mImageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.mImageId = imageId;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return mAction;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.mAction = action;
    }

}
```

and created my expandable list item which will contain a leftmenuitem parent and arraylist of children if found

```
public class ExpandableLeftMenuItem {

    LeftMenuItem mParentItem;
    ArrayList<LeftMenuItem> mChildItems;

    public ExpandableLeftMenuItem(LeftMenuItem parentItem,
            ArrayList<LeftMenuItem> childItems) {
        this.mParentItem = parentItem;
        this.mChildItems = childItems;
    }

    public LeftMenuItem getParentItem() {
        return mParentItem;
    }

    public void setParentItem(LeftMenuItem parentItem) {
        this.mParentItem = parentItem;
    }

    public ArrayList<LeftMenuItem> getChildItems() {
        return mChildItems;
    }

    public void setChildItems(ArrayList<LeftMenuItem> childItems) {
        this.mChildItems = childItems;
    }   

}
```

Then i handled`ExpandableListView` onChildClickListener and onGroupClickListener as following

```
// In Case of clicking on an item that has children, then get the action
        // of this child item and show the screen with this action
        mLeftMenu.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                if (!mLeftMenuItems.get(groupPosition).getChildItems().isEmpty()) {

                    String action = ((LeftMenuItem) mLeftMenuItems.get(groupPosition).getChildItems().get(childPosition)).getAction();
                    setSelectedSection(action);
                    handleLeftMenuClick(action);

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        // In Case of clicking on an item that has no children, then get the
        // action of this item and show the screen with this action
        mLeftMenu.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, long id) {
                if (mLeftMenuItems.get(groupPosition).getChildItems().isEmpty()) {
                    String action = ((LeftMenuItem) mLeftMenuItems.get(groupPosition).getParentItem()).getAction();
                    setSelectedSection(action);
                    handleLeftMenuClick(action);
// Return true to stop parent from expanding or collapsing group
                    return true;
                }
// Return true to handle click as parent by expanding or collapsing group
                    return false;
            }
        });
```

Then for the following

```
ExpandableListView:
     group
     group
     group
          child
          child
     group
          child
          child
```

You will create the following menu items:

```
ArrayList<ExpandableLeftMenuItem> mMenuItems = new ArrayList<ExpandableLeftMenuItem>();
mMenuItems.add(new ExpandableLeftMenuItem(new LeftMenuItem(parent1Text,parent1Image,action1),new ArrayList<LeftMenuItem>()));

mMenuItems.add(new ExpandableLeftMenuItem(new LeftMenuItem(parent2Text,parent2Image,action2),new ArrayList<LeftMenuItem>()));

ArrayList<LeftMenuItem> parent3Children = new ArrayList<LeftMenuItem>();
parent3Children.add(new LeftMenuItem(parent3Child1TextId,parent3Child1ImageId,parent3Child1action));
parent3Children.add(new LeftMenuItem(parent3Child2TextId,parent3Child2ImageId,parent3Child2action));

mMenuItems.add(new ExpandableLeftMenuItem(new LeftMenuItem(parent1Text,parent1Image,action1),parent3Children ));
```

This way, you have handled both children and group positions to take different actions.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: yeah I came up with the same solution finally, I'm currently searching for a way to only have one onclicklistener and then determine if the row is a group or child with 'instanceof' but I'm not sure that that's possible