# How can I create custom ExpandableListview

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I want to create an Android application using `ListView` or `ExpandableListView` to customize row in that list like this picture.
[image]

How can I do this? Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you need some of the items to be clickable to show other information (Clicking on a contact) and other items that are not clickable (Starting alphabet of contact list) Then using `ExpandableListView` would be the ideal solution for such a problem.

First, you need to develop a custom ExpandableListView adapter. refer to this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

After implementing this custom adapter, we are going to have two extra problems,

- Group items that are selectable and others that aren't selectable, Selectable items are contact items and Non-Selectable items are alphabets. to make this you can check this [Expandandable listview with child items at root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728513/expandandable-listview-with-child-items-at-root/21752729#21752729)
- Group items that are having more than one view, and in this case you need to add the following two methods:

L

```
final int VIEWTYPE_GROUP_CONTACT = 0;
final int VIEWTYPE_GROUP_ALPHABET = 1;
final int VIEWTYPE_GROUP_COUNT = VIEWTYPE_GROUP_ALPHABET + 1;

...

@Override
public int getGroupTypeCount() {
    return VIEWTYPE_GROUP_COUNT;
}

@Override
public int getGroupType(int groupPosition) {
    if (mGroupCollection.get(groupPosition) instanceof Alphabet)
        return VIEWTYPE_GROUP_ALPHABET;
    if (mGroupCollection.get(groupPosition) instance of ContactDetails)
        return VIEWTYPE_GROUP_CONTACT;

    return super.getGroupType(groupPosition);
}
```