# Load children on expandable listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Is there any way i can load only parent data on list view and if they have children then only load children when they expand parent with children value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use `ExpandableListView` and you might find this helpful
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Also, in order to disable parents that have children from expanding you will find this helpful
[Expandandable listview with child items at root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728513/expandandable-listview-with-child-items-at-root/21752729#21752729)