# how to hide ExpandableListView indicator for groups with no children

Tags: android, expandablelistview, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ExpandableListView - hide indicator for groups with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145090/expandablelistview-hide-indicator-for-groups-with-no-children)

hide indicator for groups with no children

main.xml

```
<ExpandableListView 
android:id="@+id/elv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:groupIndicator="@drawable/selector">
</ExpandableListView>
```

selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/expanded" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/collapse" />
</selector>
```

it doesnt work for my ICS, it seems that the state of all collapsed groups are empty

Comment: It seems to be a bug, because adapter's getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) is never called for collapsed groups. So they are treated as empty.

Answer (score 12):

Have a try at this :

```
getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(null);
```

Or else,

```
if ( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
       indicator.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
    } 
else {
       indicator.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
       indicator.setImageResource( isExpanded ? R.drawable.group_expanded : R.drawable.group_closed );
    }
```

Comment: where to put this function ?

Comment: how to get indicator in getGroupView?

Comment: getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(..) allows to set properties to it. As far as I know, there is no getter method for it.

Comment: @Swayam It'd better you complete your answer. For Accessing to ExpandableListView.setGroupIndicator(), pass it to adapter and check it on getGroupView method.

Comment: @omidnazifi : thanks for completing! :)

Comment: You can also get the instance by
    ExpandableListView v= (ExpandableListView)parent;
in getGroupView

Comment: @Swayam How to get the indicator element inside getGroupView() ???

Comment: Doesn't the above comments solve your problem?