# Hide exapandable list view icon with zero child size

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am developing an app which uses custom expandable list view. My icon changes when i click the list view. I don't want to add group indicator icon when the child size is zero. Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4562533/2683275) is of great help.

Code Snippets:

> For state_empty, you can set a different image which is not
>   confusing, or, simply use transparent color to display nothing...

Add this item in your stateful drawable along with others....

```
<item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

So, your indicator can be like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_icon_max" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_icon_min" />
</selector>
```

Explanation:

```
android:state_empty: - the element does not have any child
android:state_expanded: - state when it is expanded
android:drawable: - normal state, that is the cell has children but its not expanded
```

set the indicator like this:

```
getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.indicator));
```