# Expandable listview Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm currently learning about expandable listview in android. How to handle expansion of list? That is if the header doesn't have any children, I don't want it to expand. How to do this?
I thought of not adding that header to headerList, but I wan to display it and handle the expansion depending upon the children. Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF there is no child in the particular parent, then it won't expand (because there is nothing to show).

If your question is how to hide the group indicator when there is no child present, then put the following snippet inside `getGroupView()` :

```
if ( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
       indicator.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
    } 
else {
       indicator.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
       indicator.setImageResource( isExpanded ? R.drawable.group_expanded : R.drawable.group_closed );
    }
```

Comment: You could find more details here  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145090/expandablelistview-hide-indicator-for-groups-with-no-children

Comment: If there are no children, then how to hide/remove that header? Can it be done?

Comment: Inside getGroupView, when you are returning the view to be inflated, return an empty view with visibility Gone. Should do the trick.

Comment: There are 7 headers and in that 2 and 5th doesn't have any children. When I set the visibility to GONE, it leaves blank space in those positions. Is there any way to adjust it and make it look like list?

Comment: Oh..yeah.. that would happen. Well, I think what you need to do is remove the items from your adapter and then call notify dataset changed on your adapter. As in remove all header data which dont have any children from the dataset itself and then when you pass that dataset to the adapter, things should be fine.

Comment: Is there any way to get the number of children of respective headers on click?

Comment: getChildrenCount( groupPosition )

Comment: Where I should use it? What I want is to display toast message if there are no children. I tried on setOnGroupClickListener but there is `getChildrenCount(groupPositon)`, it has `getChildCount()` which returns total number of headers.

Comment: Inside getGroupView(), define a clickListener for the header view. When it is clicked check for the child count and display accordingly.

Comment: When I use clickListener the toast works but the other headers won't get expanded. Any idea? I have set clickListener for view.

Comment: could you kindly create a separate question and give me the link here? I mean, there are too many things on this post now. Plus it's easier to answer that way. :)