# How to hide group indicator by using groupPosition in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to hide the group indicator based on the groupPosition in ExpandableListView.

I am not using any custom groupindicator under `ExpandableListView` like below.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
<item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/my_icon_max" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_icon_min" />
</selector>
```

I cannot use `currentOffersListView.setGroupIndicator(null);` becuase this applies to all the items.

So is there any way to hide the default group indicator.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest setting the groupIndicator value to null and instead use a drawable right for your list. In the getGroupView method of your adapter, set the drawable for the view of your list row.

```
getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

with this, you can now say to your adapter that

```
if(groupPosition == x)
    drawableRight = null;

//set compoundDrawable for whatever view you are using.
```

Comment: I tried this but when i click on the group the image(custom group indicator) is disappearing.

Comment: Hi, can you post the code where you set the drawable? In my case, I use this along with the isExpanded parameter of the getGroupView method. Something along the lines of 

`getDrawable(isExpanded ? R.drawable.ic_listview_expanded : R.drawable.ic_listview_collapsed);`

Comment: Try this you may get the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145090/expandablelistview-hide-indicator-for-groups-with-no-children