# How can i disable Expandable Listview icon from it's header in android?

Tags: android

I created an `ExpandableListView` in android. I have some categories which have some more sub-categories. While other do not have sub-categories.
How can I remove the icon if it does not have a sub-category?

E.g. I have a category like Home, sarees etc. In Home, there is no sub-category so I need to remove the expandable expand icon.

This is my `content_home.xml` which has an `ExpandableListView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.domore.onlineangelnx.Home"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
    <!--android:choiceMode="singleChoice"-->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my `drawable_list_item.xml` which has a `TextView` to display `ExpandableListView` Header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my `ExpandableListViewAdapter` which counts the items and its sub-items

```
package adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.domore.onlineangelnx.R;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by MY WORLD on 10/27/2015.
 */
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String,List<String>> listDataChild;


    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild){
        this.context=context;
        this.listDataHeader=listDataHeader;
        this.listDataChild=listDataChild;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(i)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return this.listDataHeader.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        String headerTitle=(String)getGroup(i);

        if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item,null);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        final String childText=(String)getChild(i,i1);

        if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_tems,null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my Home.java (MainActivity.java) which sets the argument for `List<String>` and `HashMap<String,List<String>>`

```
package com.domore.onlineangelnx;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import MainFragments.HomeFragment;
import MainFragments.SareesFragment;
import adapter.ExpandableListAdapter;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private ExpandableListAdapter adapter=null;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    private String[] navMenuItems;

    private List<String> listDataHeader=null;
    private HashMap<String,List<String>> listDataChild=null;
    private ExpandableListView mDrawerList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mTitle=mDrawerTitle=getTitle();

        navMenuItems=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_item);

        mDrawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        //Setting adapter
        prepareListData();

        adapter=new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),listDataHeader,listDataChild);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                return groupPosition == 0;
            }
        });

        mDrawerList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Fragment fragment = null;

                switch (groupPosition) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        switch (childPosition) {
                            case 0:
                                fragment=new SareesFragment();
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                if (fragment != null) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
                    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(childPosition, true);
                    mDrawerList.setSelection(childPosition);
                    setTitle(navMenuItems[childPosition]);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                } else {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            //displayView(0);
        }

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
    private void prepareListData(){
        listDataHeader=new ArrayList<>();
        listDataChild=new HashMap<>();

        listDataHeader.add(navMenuItems[0]);
        listDataHeader.add(navMenuItems[1]);
        listDataHeader.add(navMenuItems[2]);
        listDataHeader.add(navMenuItems[3]);
        listDataHeader.add(navMenuItems[4]);
        listDataHeader.add(navMenuItems[5]);
        listDataHeader.add(navMenuItems[6]);

        List<String> home=new ArrayList<>();

                                            //Sub-Menu For SAREES
        List<String> sarees=new ArrayList<>();
        sarees.add("a");
        sarees.add("b");
        sarees.add("c");
        sarees.add("d");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1),sarees);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;

            case R.id.action_search:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment=new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment=new SareesFragment();
                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            case 3:

                break;
            case 4:

                break;
            case 5:

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuItems[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        try {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145090/expandablelistview-hide-indicator-for-groups-with-no-children

Comment: @MilanGajera.. Plz try below lines of code...and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all , remove the default icon of expandable listview

```
<ExpandableListView [...] 
    android:groupIndicator="@null" />
```

And than in your adapter of Expandable listview in `getGroupView` method use following code for it

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LIST_GROUP_XML, null);
    }

    TextView header_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_header_tv);
    ImageView arrow_iv =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_iv);


    header_tv.setText(headerTitle);

    Boolean check = false;

    try {


        YOUR_HAS_MAP_LIST.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(0);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        check = true;
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(check)
    {
        arrow_iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    if(isExpanded)
    {
        arrow_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.UP_ARROW);
    }
    else
    {
        arrow_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.DOWN_ARROW);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: When i click on any one of category at a time other category's icon also hidden?

Answer (score 0):

There is single problem in above answer. While you expand the category other category's icon was also disable. Because, at the first time code goes to try and it's not goes outside of try until your listdatachild.get(listdataheader.get(i)).get(0) found. so, it not going to in if(check) everytime. Therefor, icon were remaing hidden.

Below is the perfect solution

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LIST_GROUP_XML, null);
    }

    TextView header_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_header_tv);
    ImageView arrow_iv =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_iv);


    header_tv.setText(headerTitle);

    Boolean check = false;

    try {


        if(YOUR_HAS_MAP_LIST.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(0)==null){}
        else{
             if (isExpanded) {
                arrow_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up);
            } else {
                arrow_iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
            }
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        check = true;
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(check)
    {
        arrow_iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        arrow_iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```