# Implementing expandable list view with two child views open all the time and the remaining child list to open on group click?

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview

How can I implement this ?
I have found solutions to expand groupviews to show all the children lists using expandgroup(groupposition), but can't find solution to do specifically this

Comment: Refer this solution :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34563377/3946958

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve, please elaborate and post some code so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this library: [Expandable Recycler View](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)

If I understand correctly what you want to implement, you can manually open first and second items in, for example, on activity created and override `collapse()` method for items not to close. These items will be expandable views by itself and open on your click.