# how to hide group indicator if no child in expendablelistview in android

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = null;
    HashMap<String, List<ExpandableListItem>> _child;
    String response;
    String serviceName, serviceIcon, serviceId;
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    CustomExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    String groupName;
    String childName;
    List<ExpandableListItem> listtG1;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    List<ExpandableListItem> _header;
    ExpandableListItem rowData;
    List<String> _groupNameList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.user_name));
        new CategoryServices().execute("");

        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

                groupName = _groupNameList.get(groupPosition);
                listtG1 = _child.get(groupName);
                Log.d("ListSize", String.valueOf(listtG1.size()));

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,groupName+""+childName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,groupName+""+childName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

                groupName = _groupNameList.get(groupPosition);
                listtG1 = _child.get(groupName);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, groupName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("ListSize", String.valueOf(listtG1.size()));


                if (listtG1.size() == 1 && listtG1.get(0).getServiceName().equals(groupName)) {
                    expandableListView.setGroupIndicator(null);


                    return  true;
                }



                return false;

            }
        });


        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {


                childName = listtG1.get(childPosition).getServiceName();
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        childName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();


                return false;
            }
        });


        dynamicToolbarColor();

        toolbarTextAppernce();
    }


    private void dynamicToolbarColor() {

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.profile_pic);
        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setContentScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimary));
                collapsingToolbarLayout.setStatusBarScrimColor(palette.getMutedColor(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark));
            }
        });
    }


    private void toolbarTextAppernce() {
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.collapsedappbar);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.expandedappbar);
    }


    class CategoryServices extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            response = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://cpanel.smartindiaservice.com/api/categoryservices?categoryid=13");

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {

                setListAdapter(result, expandableListView);

//                        return false;
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {

            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }


    private void setListAdapter(String response, ExpandableListView expandableListView) {
        _child = new HashMap<>();
        _groupNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!response.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                if (jsonArray != null && jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject productObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String groupName = productObj.getString("Service");
                        JSONArray servicesArray = productObj.getJSONArray("SubServices");
                        if (servicesArray != null && servicesArray.length() > 0) {
                            _header = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < servicesArray.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject serviceObj = servicesArray.getJSONObject(j);
                                rowData = new ExpandableListItem();
                                serviceName = serviceObj.getString("SubServiceName");
                                serviceIcon = serviceObj.getString("SubServiceDescription");
                                serviceId = serviceObj.getString("SubServiceID");
                                rowData.setGroupName(groupName);
                                rowData.setServiceIcon(serviceIcon);
                                rowData.setServiceId(serviceId);
                                rowData.setServiceName(serviceName);
                                _header.add(rowData);


                            }


                        }
                        _child.put(groupName, _header);
                        _groupNameList.add(groupName);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, _groupNameList, _child);
            expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        }

    }


}
```

public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private HashMap<String, List<ExpandableListItem>> expandableListDetail;

    public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                       HashMap<String, List<ExpandableListItem>> expandableListDetail) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//        final String expandedListText = getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition).g;

        ExpandableListItem rowData = (ExpandableListItem) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
        expandedListTextView.setText(rowData.getServiceName());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.expandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

this is my activity and adapter i am able to display data in expandable list-view i want show indicator when group contain more than one child and i want hide group indicator when group contain only one child and group name and child name is same i am trying to in activity           expandableListView.setGroupIndicator(null); using this code on setOnGroupClickListener this click but what happed firs time it display all indicator and when i click on group whose child is one and name same then it hide all indicator please suggest me how to fix this issue

Comment: see this link then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145090/expandablelistview-hide-indicator-for-groups-with-no-children

Comment: getExpandableListView how it will come ?