# How to disable the expandable list view icon

Tags: java, android, navigation

i want to disable the expandable list view item on my Navigation drawer. 
Right now, i disabled the expandable list view Icon on the list view with this Code:

```
 android:groupIndicator="@null"
```

But that is not what I want. I want the Icon, if there are submenus on that item. If there are no submenus, then there should not be a expandable list view Icon. That is my List Adapter. Does anyone knows, how to implement it?

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ExpandedMenuModel> mListDataHeader; // header titles

    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<ExpandedMenuModel, List<String>> mListDataChild;
    ExpandableListView expandList;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<ExpandedMenuModel> listDataHeader, HashMap<ExpandedMenuModel, List<String>> listChildData, ExpandableListView mView) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mListDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.mListDataChild = listChildData;
        this.expandList = mView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        int i = mListDataHeader.size();
        Log.d("GROUPCOUNT", String.valueOf(i));
        return this.mListDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        int childCount = 0;
        if (groupPosition != 1) {   //War ursprünglich != 2 !!!
            childCount = this.mListDataChild.get(this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
        }
        return childCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        Log.d("CHILD", mListDataChild.get(this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosition).toString());
        return this.mListDataChild.get(this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ExpandedMenuModel headerTitle = (ExpandedMenuModel) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.listheader, null);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.submenu);

        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle.getIconName());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_submenu, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.submenu);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExpandableListView - hide indicator for groups with no children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145090/expandablelistview-hide-indicator-for-groups-with-no-children)

Comment: I tried the post before, but it doesn't helped me