# How to change the layout file in the activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to change the the XML file in my expandabl list view Adapter. But there is no OnCreate method. I saw a couple of Code samples with the OnCreate method. But is there a way to do it without it? I want to put it on my getGroupView method. In to the if-question.

Sorry, but I'am new on Android Studio :/ I Need a little bit time to understand all the things :)

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ExpandedMenuModel headerTitle = (ExpandedMenuModel) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.listheader, null);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.submenu);

        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle.getIconName());

        if ( getChildrenCount( groupPosition ) == 0 ) {
             //HERE I WANT TO PUT IT IN
        } else {
            //HERE I WANT TO PUT IT IN
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
            android:background="@android:color/white">
        </ExpandableListView>


        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: onCreate is for the activity. In your case you are trying to inflate the view in a list adapter. The above code should work. If its not working, post the exception and other details

Comment: The Code works. But I want to disable the expandable list view Icons, if there is no Sub menu. How I can implement it in to the if-function at the bottom?

Comment: Similar to how you get the reference lblListHeader , you should be able to get other reference and toggle visibility as required. If that is not the question, please post the layout xml and screenshot of current thing if possible

Comment: I updated my question. there you can see for example, that share is just one item. But there is still the Icon. If I put the line ANDROID:GROUPINDICATOR="@ANDROID:COLOR/TRANSPARENT" to the layout file, then all the Icons get removed. But that is not what i want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145090/expandablelistview-hide-indicator-for-groups-with-no-children