# ListView multiple select with custom layout

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to make a gmail-like listview. That is, initially, the listview is in single choice mode, but when a checkbok is selected, it becomes multiple choice.

this is what i have so far:

```
     SimpleCursorAdapter dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cursor,
             new String[]{"_id","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"}, 
             new int[] { R.id.checkBox1, R.id.a, R.id.b, R.id.c, R.id.d, R.id.e}
// all of these are a part of my list item custom layout.
             );

    dataSource.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View aView, final Cursor c, int i) {

    String s=c.getString(i);
    String toset="";
    TextView tv = i==0?null: (TextView) aView;
    if (i==0){
        if(chkL==null){
            chkL=new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb1, boolean isChecked) {
                    CheckBox cb=(CheckBox) cb1;
                    chkid[c.getPosition()]=isChecked;

                    if(lv.getChoiceMode()!=lv.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE){
                        lv.setChoiceMode(lv.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                    }
                    lv.setItemChecked(c.getPosition()+1,isChecked);
                    log(isChecked+" selected "+(c.getPosition()+1));
                }

        };
        }

        CheckBox cb= (CheckBox) aView;
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(chkL);

        return (i==0);
    }};
```

Currently I am trying to at least make the item "selected" by pressing the checkbox against it. I am using `c.getPosition()+1` (cursor's position) to get the position of the list item tapped. but that always seems to return `1` or sometimes, random values.

**update:**
Looks like it always returns 1, but when i iterate through getCheckedItemPositions(), i see that item no. 10 gets selected. Tap another checkbox, again the cursor position will be 1 but item no 11 will get selected and so on. But if i tap outside the checkbox, the correct item is selected.

Also, on selecting one checkbox, if you scroll down, you would see that several other checkboxes are checked. (I have about 255 items in the list). I think its due to android's way of reusing the same checkboxes ?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is an ExpandableListView.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483690/expandablelistview-sample-from-google

Answer (score 0):

I would try a slightly different approach:

- Keep the ListView as `SINGLE_CHOICE`, but set each row's CheckBox with a listener that adds / removes the row's `id` to a List called `checkedRows` (for example).
- When you want to delete, move, star, etc the checked rows: iterate through `checkedRows` and perform the necessary action.

I believe that is simpler than changing switching back and forth between multiple types of the default states and functionality.

**Addition**

I have never overridden `setViewValue()`, but this should work:

```
CheckBox cb= (CheckBox) aView;
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(chkL);
cb.setTag(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_id"))); // Add this
```

and in your `onClickListener()`:

```
long id = (Long) cb1.getTag();
```

Comment: But how do you get the row id in the listener function? Thats where im going wrong.

Comment: @arnab321 Sorry about the delay, this comment slipped past me. I added an update if you haven't solved this already.

Comment: i dont think that is going to work, as i also mentioned the issue of duplicate checkboxes getting ticked, as android reuses the Views. If you do `setTag` to just one checkbox and scroll down a bit, you will encounter more checkboxes with the same tag.

Comment: I have used this method with an extended CursorAdapter by setting the tag in `newView()` and recalling the tag inside one OnCheckedChangeListener for every CheckBox flawlessly. Sorry you think it won't work.